# Cannot read property 'call' of underfined

Tags: angular, undefined, bootstrap-4

Getting the following console error when trying to run an angular 2 app, can anyone advise on where my problems might lie? Happens straight upon hitting the site.

```
error_handler.ts:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8f0b7e24f73d46f85c7f:54)
    at src async:28
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:256)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:142)
    at zone.js:844
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:245)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8f0b7e24f73d46f85c7f:54)
    at src async:28
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:392)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:256)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:142)
    at zone.js:844
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:245)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:766)
    at zone.js:844
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:245)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Is `call` a variable you've declared?

Answer (score 0):

you can cheat it by `--aot` with ng serve or ng build